# Converting RTP data to RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtp, live-streaming

I am having a live stream of ts data. I streamed this with an rtp header and received it in an android device using vlc. Now i would like to stream the same stream using rtsp protocol. How can I do this. Is there some method for using this rtp data for streaming rtsp?

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is just an RTP streaming initiation protocol, it's very simple and can be easily implemented just after reading RFC. It will take some time (and reading) though to implement RTCP protocol